# Enable destructuring objects rest properties with Babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I noticed that Babel wasn't transforming this:

```
function({ param, ...rest }) {}
```

This syntax is already supported in the latest popular browsers. However, according to Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it's not supported in browsers as new as Edge 79 (released this year).

I tried manually enabling some Babel plugins, but it didn't work:

```
@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring
@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread
@babel/plugin-transform-parameters
```

Is it possible to transform this syntax with Babel? I need to do testing in older browsers, but I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid property id` because of this.

Comment: in what way did you manually-enable the plugins?

Comment: did you set it up as per [instructions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-destructuring)?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `babel` needs to combine more than one plugins to transform something. In this case I think you would need to combine at least 2 plugins:

- `@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring`
- `@babel/plugin-transform-parameters`

```json
npx babel /path/to/yourFile plugins=@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring,@babel/plugin-transform-parameters
```

To make life easier, I would suggest to use `preset-env` instead which supports official ES changes (since it includes all official plugins for you):

```sh
npx babel /path/to/yourFile presets=@babel/preset-env
```

Comment: I included all 4 plugins listed, along with `preset-env`, it didn't work. Maybe I'll try removing `preset-env`

Comment: It should work that way. Do you have a reproducible repo anyway?